# How to add path to an Azure App Gateway Backend Pool?

Tags: azure, api-gateway, azure-application-gateway

I have 2 WebAPIs with different paths like below:

> xx.xxx.xx.xxx/Users
>
> xx.xxx.xx.xxx/Roles
>
> yy.yyy.yy.yyy/Documents

I tried to setup Azure App Gateway using path-based redirection to achieve this:

> myApiGateway.com/v1/Users
>
> myGateway.com/v1/Roles
>
> myGateway.com/v1/Documents

But in backend pools, I cannot configure IP (or FQDN) with extra path like xx.xxx.xx.xxx/path.

[image: Screenshot]

**MORE INFORMATION UPDATE:**

In the path-based rule configuration, it would look like

> /v1/Users/* ->      Pool X (xx.xxx.xx.xxx)
>
> /v1/Roles/* ->      Pool X (xx.xxx.xx.xxx)
>
> /v1/Documents/* - > Pool Y (yy.yyy.yy.yyy)

My front-end API consumer requires one and only URL like

> http://myApiGateway.com/v1/

They would not prefer to go to http://myApiGateway.com/v1/api-x/ for users and roles and http://myApiGateway.com/v1/api-y/ for documents.

Right now I'm thinking of api-x and api-y are somehow not best practices regarding design.

Any thoughts, suggestions, advises on this, I would very appreciate. Thanks!

Comment: did you already try xx.xxx.xx.xxx/Users/*  ?

Comment: Yes I tried but it's not valid. The application gateway backend pool is only allow IP or FQDN.

Answer (score 0):

Backend pools of Application Gateway can only be IP or FQDN. I think what you need is Path-based redirection: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/tutorial-url-redirect-powershell

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I was actually configuring it using path-based redirection as well. I think my problem is somehow related to its design.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure [path based routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-create-url-route-portal). You should have one backend pool called X with servers which can accept requests for `/v1/Users/*` and `/v1/Roles/*`. You should have another backend pool called Y with servers which can accept requests from URI path `/v1/Documents/*`. You can then have one listener which accepts traffic from `http://myapiGateway.com`. You would then add a path based routing rule with 3 paths - which directs `/v1/Users/*` and `/v1/Roles/*` traffic to pool X and `/v1/Documents/*` to backend pool Y.

Answer (score 0):

I have accomplished this by using different HTTP Settings records for each route. Within an HTTP Setting there is an another "Route" property which is only visible in Powershell. You may refer to this [post](https://vincentlauzon.com/2017/05/08/url-routing-with-azure-application-gateway/) for some briefs.

So it's basically described below:

- "/Users" route

`Backend Pool: xx.xxx.xx.xxx
HttpSettings.Route: "/Users"
Path-based rule: "/v1/Users/*`

- "/Roles" route

`Backend Pool: xx.xxx.xx.xxx
HttpSettings.Route: "/Roles"
Path-based rule: "/v1/Roles/*`

- "/Documents" route

`Backend Pool: yy.yyy.yy.yyy
HttpSettings.Route: "/Documents"
Path-based rule: "/v1/Documents/*`

If I have e.g. an another "Tickets" API which serves at root level, I would have:

`Backend Pool: zz.zzz.zz.zzz
HttpSettings.Route: "/"
Path-based rule: "/v1/Tickets/*`